# Cant withdraw element from collection of EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i need to select item by id from view to controller and then send item to another view.
My first view, where im send id of item to Edit action:

```html
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Raw("<img style='width:80px; height:60px;' src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,"
                                + Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image) + "\" />")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Personal", new { id = item.Id }, null)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Delete", "Personal", new { id = item.Id}, null)
                </td>
            </tr>
    }
```

My Edit action

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        ApplicationUser au = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        Picture pic = new Picture();
        foreach (var item in au.Pictures)
        {
            if (id == item.Id)
            {
                pic = item;
            }
        }
        //Picture pic = new Picture { Id = id, Image = image};
        return View(pic);
    }
```

And view that wait for item

```html
@model Dip_prj1.Models.Picture
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
             @Html.Raw("<img style='width:80px; height:60px;' src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,"
                                + Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image) + "\" />")>
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Вернуться к списку", "UserDetails", "Personal", new { id = User.Identity.GetUserId() }, null)
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem in the Edit controller, cause error write that i send empty byte array. Help me please.

Comment: Any reason you're using the `@Html.Raw()` helper in your HTML? Why not just use `@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image)` instead?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and properly explain the problem you're having. "error write that i send empty byte array" is not clear.

Comment: Before sending pic object check in debug its Image property. Maybe it is null

Comment: @DespeiL , you're right, but i dont know why it sending null. Cause i looked in debugger and ID had right argument, and Image column of this id isnt empty or null.
>An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>Additional information: Value can not be null.

Comment: Why the foreach (var item in au.Pictures)?
Why not au.Pictures.Where(p=>p.Id == id).First() ?

Comment: @Jonny because I don't how to use linq requests. =\

Comment: @ArtemDanchenko It may be a bit off topic, but I think you would benefit from looking into linq. It's like SQL but backwards. The benefit is that it allows for a query to be sent to your database without transferring massive amounts of data to the application.

Comment: I would suggest making a special action that returns a binary image. Then you can add it to your markup like any other image.
Maybe UserController has an Image action and you can link to the image somehting like /User/Image/{imageID}

Comment: @Jonny i changed foreach to your linq query and ...
>An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>Additional information: The sequence contains no elements
but i have elements by this ID
 ![valid XHTML][checkmark].
 
[checkmark]: http://puu.sh/rPxhm/4f0ad7b215.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ty all guys for helping, problem was in making Application user type object, i forgot to put part where it must load collection from another table. It should be like `ApplicationUser au = db.Users.Include(t => t.Pictures).FirstOrDefault(t => (t.Id) == user);
This Include was clue`